# How to recover lost data after disk MBR to GPT conversion?

Tags: partition, data-recovery, gpt

When I curiously selected to "create a new partition table" and the new type of it is GPT, GParted poped a warning message that "I may loss all...", but I still clicked yes, as I thought all the operations on the disk would be listed in a window and waited for my confirm.

But no, the creation just started imediatly, all my data and partition got lost now, how to recover the lost data and partitions after the conversion is finished?

Comment: A common disk rescue tools would be `ddrescue`, `photorec` or `testdisk`. You will need a drive to which the recovery can go, might not be able to recover all data and might loose filenames. On the other hand you could try to go back to MBR and run an MBR recovery tool - allowing you to skip the longish data rescue. Best is then to copy the whole drive and thus avoid a few dangers.

Comment: There is still no answer for the case of not recovering the original partition. In my case, I do not want to recover the MBR partition, and I just want to find a few old "MBR files" that I have forgotten to backup. I do not want to reset my whole new GPT partitioned Windows installation for that.

Answer (score 2):

Try `testdisk`.

It successfully recovered the original partition schema and data for me when I selected the wrong device and applied the changes. Recovery of the schema and entire filesystem succeeded in moments and without copying to a new destination.

Guide is [here](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step)

Comment: After recovery by 'testdisk' what type of partition table is?

Comment: For me, `testdisk` detected the original partition type (I had overwritten GPT with FAT) and gave me the option to recover the original.

Comment: Best advice is, if you have a spare HDD then `dd` an image before going any further. At least you have a 'restore point' if it all goes wring.

Comment: Yeah testdisk saves me! It gives me confident to convert my DOS disk to GPT with sensive data.

Answer (score 0):

This shall be an answer for those who do not want to recover the original partitions, but who want to recover selected files instead. In other words, I do not want to recover the MBR partition just to get the files back. I just want to find a few old MBR files that I have forgotten to backup, I do not want to reset my whole new GPT partitioned Windows installation for that.

In my case, I once had an MBR Windows installation with a username called Admin. I need to find the files that are in that Windows user path, using Linux.

*First of all, do not put recovery programs and their output on those drives which you want to recover. This is to avoid any overwriting of files. And make a backup before you go on.*

**testdisk**

In testdisk, I would only be able to choose "[Image Creation]" or "[Type]" to change the partition type, or copy the files of a given *partition* to a destination folder using "P" and "c"- which does not help if I cannot find the MBR partition that I need. There are two MBR partitions shown when you choose "Intel" (= MBR) instead of "GPT", but I cannot find the older MBR partition with that old Windows username that I had at the very start. It seems as if double installation of MBR and double installation of GPT have finally overwritten the information of the oldest data, which is possible, as the Windows installations will be able to overwrite files and partition information.

**photorec**

I tried photorec that is installed with testdisk. For a full guide, see [this tutorial](https://www.journaldev.com/37328/photorec-recover-deleted-files-in-linux-ubuntu). Photorec has the disadvantage that the file structure gets lost.

*Short photorec guide:*

Choose "Partition: Unknown [Whole disk]", then a destination folder, then press c to start the recovery. Before selecting [Search] in the "Partition" menu, do not forget to choose the file types under [File Opt], elsewise photorec will take hours. At first I had overseen that, same as [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/311952/photorec-not-asking-for-file-types). Find the right file types [here](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/File_Formats_Recovered_By_PhotoRec), for example, .avi and .wav are not as such in the list, but are called RIFF video / RIFF audio.*

Unfortunately, I could not recover my avi / wav files of the lost Windows MBR  partition using Linux photorec *because I could not find my old MBR partition*, the same problem as I had in testdisk, and this is not astonishing as both programs are the same package.

**R-Studio recovery family**

If you want to keep the file structure and / or recover more file types, you should search further. For example, try the R-studio family of "rtt" company (r-tools technology): the free [**R-Linux**](https://www.r-studio.com/free-linux-recovery/) is offered for both Windows and Linux installations and can recover Linux formats. Without having tested it, its Windows brother "R-Undelete" which can even keep the file structure is promising enough to choose this.

*In order to check it with "R-Undelete", I took out the ssd and plugged it to a Windows computer as an external drive. But even a deep scan has not found the old MBR partition.*

R-Linux was also recommended by [How to recover deleted files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files)

**Further alternatives**

Search the last link for further alternatives.
Elsewise, just take the hard way, follow the other answer and convert back to MBR.

---

Summing it up: I was unable to recover my files with testdisk or photorec. I guess that in my case it is because I have installed Windows twice on an MBR partition scheme and twice on a GPT partition system, with the mere Windows files overwriting the old files that I was searching for. There is a small chance that there is a limit of steps that the recovery programs can turn back, as I have installed Windows four times over the oldest partition in question. I do not think that there is a limit of "going back", instead, the files and the partitioning information are probably just overwritten.

That means that the steps described might well help someone else, but not in my case.

Comment: A long-winded rambling answer that answered nothing!